# Deploying Orchard CMS to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: visual-studio, azure, amazon-web-services, orchardcms, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I asked this on the Orchard community forums and got crickets...

How does one deploy Orchard CMS into a proper cloud style deployment (ephemeral/stateless servers) on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk?

There is a standard and an Azure solution file for Visual Studio. I'm not a developer so I'm kinda lost in VS-2015. I would have thought I could deploy using the normal (not azure specific) solution and utilized S3 for storage and and RDS instance for database. However, I just keep running into walls. I would like to be able to utilize all the VPC infrustructure and investment we have in AWS for this if possible.